# StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() hung for the second command

Tags: asp.net, process

I have to run two commands using Process in asp.net as given below and the first command runs successfully while running the second command gets hung at **result = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()**

How to implement this to run both commands successfully?

```
private static string FFMPEG_EXE_PATH = @"D:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe";
private static string FFPROBE_EXE_PATH = @"D:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string firstArgs = @"-hide_banner -show_format -show_streams -pretty D:\Video\dolbycanyon.m4v";

    var result1 = Execute(FFPROBE_EXE_PATH, firstArgs);

    string secondArgs = @"-hide_banner -ss 00:00:05 -i D:\Video\dolbycanyon.m4v -r 1 -t 1 -f image2 D:\Video\test.jpg";

    var result2 = Execute(FFMPEG_EXE_PATH, secondArgs);
}

private string Execute(string exePath, string parameters)
{
    string result = String.Empty;

    using (Process p = new Process())
    {
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = exePath;
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = parameters;
        p.Start();
        result = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); // the application hung here for the second command
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the second command manually to see why it is hanging?

Comment: @Martin yes, the second command is running smoothly in command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the **Execute** method to as below and it worked for both commands.

```
 public string Execute(string path, string args, int timeoutMs)
 {
    using (var outputWaitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false))
    {

        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            var sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                sb.AppendLine(e.Data);
                if (e.Data == null)
                {
                    outputWaitHandle.Set();
                }
            };

            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();

            process.WaitForExit(timeoutMs);
            outputWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeoutMs);

            process.CancelOutputRead();

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```